# Normalizing Twitter JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, api

Relevant packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
```

I am struggling to normalize some JSON output from the Twitter API. Everything is being done with Python. I am using the `pd.json_normalize` function to try to normalize the JSON output below, and I have attempted many methods. The problem I seem to be running into is that the referenced tweets portion of the response does not show up in every response (presumably because there are no referenced Tweets for that response). I have not seen this situation covered on any forums or articles online, so hoping that we can get a good solution here for myself and anyone else running into this issue to reference.

The code I have been using to try to normalize looks like

```
df_test=pd.json_normalize(json_response, 
                          record_path='data',
                          errors='ignore'
                          )
```

and I have tinkered around with the parameters a lot but cannot get it to work. Hoping that a wiser coder can help me solve this issue.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-12T17:00:25.000Z",
            "id": "1558136333867970560",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 11,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 7
            },
            "referenced_tweets": [
                {
                    "id": "1558084759812710401",
                    "type": "quoted"
                }
            ],
            "text": "\ud83d\udce3There\u2019s still time to register for #Chirp!\u23f"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T22:04:00.000Z",
            "id": "1557850345392377856",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 18,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 2,
                "retweet_count": 5
            },
            "text": "Discover how @ListenFirst, a social analytics platform and Twitter @OfficialPartner, improved their efficiency and accuracy by leveraging the v2 API. \ud83d\udca1\ud83d\udcbb\n\nRead it here \u2b07\ufe0f \"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T21:35:15.000Z",
            "id": "1557843109681123328",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 14,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 1,
                "retweet_count": 3
            },
            "referenced_tweets": [
                {
                    "id": "1553987008355254272",
                    "type": "quoted"
                }
            ],
            "text": "\ud83d\ude80\ud83e\udd29\u2728"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T21:25:01.000Z",
            "id": "1557840534252662784",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 1,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 0
            },
            "referenced_tweets": [
                {
                    "id": "1557737011041038337",
                    "type": "replied_to"
                }
            ],
            "text": "@talkshrey @talkshrey this is awesome, we can\u2019t wait to see what you build! \ud83d\ude80"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T18:00:09.000Z",
            "id": "1557788977842765827",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 18,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 2,
                "retweet_count": 8
            },
            "text": "\ud83d\udce3 There is only ONE DAY LEFT to register to attend the #Chirp Developer Conference in person! \n\nGet your applications in by 11:59pm PT on Friday, August 12, so you don\u2019t miss out on your chance to attend. \ud83d\udcc5\ud83d\udc40\n\nRegister here \u2935\ufe0f "
        },
        {
            "author_id": "1555310752176668675",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T16:30:53.000Z",
            "id": "1557766512915742722",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 0,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 0
            },
            "text": "yo! what's wrong with the bird app today??\ni can't follow, neither be followed!!?\n#twitter #TwitterDown #twitterdev"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "1550706584204021762",
            "created_at": "2022-08-11T05:59:09.000Z",
            "id": "1557607534596431873",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 1,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 0
            },
            "referenced_tweets": [
                {
                    "id": "1539383247355793408",
                    "type": "replied_to"
                }
            ],
            "text": "@fake_Awareness @Eminem I was thinking about enter #TwitterDev #Chirp and writing a application for #HackAThon that would find every scammers account by AI algorithms."
        },
        {
            "author_id": "1512404349598957573",
            "created_at": "2022-08-10T18:12:36.000Z",
            "id": "1557429723357401088",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 0,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 0
            },
            "text": "#TwitterDev"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "1389763639159230464",
            "created_at": "2022-08-10T15:22:48.000Z",
            "id": "1557386991607627776",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 0,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 0,
                "retweet_count": 0
            },
            "text": "#twitterdeveloper #twitterdev #twitterapi\nwhy can i only make sense of it doesn't drast\u2026."
        },
        {
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "created_at": "2022-08-09T17:58:58.000Z",
            "id": "1557063904655654912",
            "public_metrics": {
                "like_count": 11,
                "quote_count": 0,
                "reply_count": 1,
                "retweet_count": 4
            },
            "referenced_tweets": [
                {
                    "id": "1557063868551114752",
                    "type": "replied_to"
                }
            ],
            "text": "\u23f3 Time is running out to enter the #ChirpDevChallenge!\n\nSubmit your app by August 19th with an app in one of our three categories and help people unlock brand new experiences on Twitter. \ud83d\udcbb\u2699\ufe0f\n\nJoin the challenge \u2b07"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "newest_id": "1558136333867970560",
        "oldest_id": "1557063904655654912",
        "result_count": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `json.normalize`? I see `pd.json_normalize`.

Comment: @Jortega Typo in the former case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dct` is your dictionary from the question you can do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dct["data"]).explode("referenced_tweets")
df["referenced_id"] = np.where(
    df["referenced_tweets"].notna(), df["referenced_tweets"].str["id"], ""
)

df["referenced_type"] = np.where(
    df["referenced_tweets"].notna(), df["referenced_tweets"].str["type"], ""
)

df.pop("referenced_tweets")

df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("public_metrics").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             author_id                created_at                   id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    text        referenced_id referenced_type  like_count  quote_count  reply_count  retweet_count
0           2244994945  2022-08-12T17:00:25.000Z  1558136333867970560                                                                                                                                                                                            There’s still time to register for #Chirp!ȿ  1558084759812710401          quoted          11            0            0              7
1           2244994945  2022-08-11T22:04:00.000Z  1557850345392377856                                                             Discover how @ListenFirst, a social analytics platform and Twitter @OfficialPartner, improved their efficiency and accuracy by leveraging the v2 API. \n\nRead it here ⬇️                                               18            0            2              5
2           2244994945  2022-08-11T21:35:15.000Z  1557843109681123328                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ✨  1553987008355254272          quoted          14            0            1              3
3           2244994945  2022-08-11T21:25:01.000Z  1557840534252662784                                                                                                                                                           @talkshrey @talkshrey this is awesome, we can’t wait to see what you build!   1557737011041038337      replied_to           1            0            0              0
4           2244994945  2022-08-11T18:00:09.000Z  1557788977842765827   There is only ONE DAY LEFT to register to attend the #Chirp Developer Conference in person! \n\nGet your applications in by 11:59pm PT on Friday, August 12, so you don’t miss out on your chance to attend. \n\nRegister here ⤵️                                                18            0            2              8
5  1555310752176668675  2022-08-11T16:30:53.000Z  1557766512915742722                                                                                                                   yo! what's wrong with the bird app today??\ni can't follow, neither be followed!!?\n#twitter #TwitterDown #twitterdev                                                0            0            0              0
6  1550706584204021762  2022-08-11T05:59:09.000Z  1557607534596431873                                                                 @fake_Awareness @Eminem I was thinking about enter #TwitterDev #Chirp and writing a application for #HackAThon that would find every scammers account by AI algorithms.  1539383247355793408      replied_to           1            0            0              0
7  1512404349598957573  2022-08-10T18:12:36.000Z  1557429723357401088                                                                                                                                                                                                                             #TwitterDev                                                0            0            0              0
8  1389763639159230464  2022-08-10T15:22:48.000Z  1557386991607627776                                                                                                                                              #twitterdeveloper #twitterdev #twitterapi\nwhy can i only make sense of it doesn't drast….                                                0            0            0              0
9           2244994945  2022-08-09T17:58:58.000Z  1557063904655654912                ⏳ Time is running out to enter the #ChirpDevChallenge!\n\nSubmit your app by August 19th with an app in one of our three categories and help people unlock brand new experiences on Twitter. ⚙️\n\nJoin the challenge ⬇  1557063868551114752      replied_to          11            0            1              4
```

---

EDIT: Updated answer with `public_metrics`

Comment: This solution doesn't quite work because the resulting df doesn't have the public_metrics. I can definitely work with this because I can merge this df I was getting before (which doesn't have the referenced_tweets normalized) but is there a way to get the correct df without merging?

Comment: @Andrew986 Updated answer with `public_metrics`